# Linux: Change argv[1] recursively through file sytem

Tags: linux

Ok, so what I have right now is a c++ program that does work (replacing things) to files. The thing i need to do now is run this program on a folder. Pretty much run it on all .cpp and .h files in the folder. the program runs like :

```
program filename.cpp
```

so how do i recursively change that filename for each file in the folder/location of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

```
find some/dir \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec program {} \;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much for a quick response too.